# Scrapy ignoring the content of second page

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I've written a tiny scraper in python scrapy to parse different names from a webpage. The page has traversed 4 more pages through pagination. The total names throughout the pages are 46 but it is scraping 36 names.

The scraper is supposed to skip the content of first landing pages but using `parse_start_url` argument in my scraper I've handled it.

However, the problem I'm facing at this moment with this scraper is that It surprisingly skips the content of second page and parse all the rest, I meant first page, third page, fourth page and so on. Why it is happening and how to deal with that? Thanks in advance.

Here is the script I'm trying with:

```
import scrapy

class DataokSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "dataoksp"
    start_urls = ["https://data.ok.gov/browse?page=1&f[0]=bundle_name%3ADataset&f[1]=im_field_categories%3A4191"]

    def parse(self, response):
        for link in response.css('.pagination .pager-item a'):
            new_link = link.css("::attr(href)").extract_first()
            yield scrapy.Request(url=response.urljoin(new_link), callback=self.target_page)

    def target_page(self, response):
        parse_start_url = self.target_page  # I used this argument to capture the content of first page
        for titles in response.css('.title a'):
            name = titles.css("::text").extract_first()
            yield {'Name':name}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution turns out to be very easy. I've fixed it already.

```
import scrapy

class DataokSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "dataoksp"
    start_urls = ["https://data.ok.gov/browse?f[0]=bundle_name%3ADataset&f[1]=im_field_categories%3A4191"]

    def parse(self, response):
        for f_link in self.start_urls:
            yield response.follow(url=f_link, callback=self.target_page) #this is line which fixes the issue

        for link in response.css('.pagination .pager-item a'):
            new_link = link.css("::attr(href)").extract_first()
            yield response.follow(url=new_link, callback=self.target_page)

    def target_page(self, response):
        for titles in response.css('.title a'):
            name = titles.css("::text").extract_first()
            yield {'Name':name}
```

Now it gives me all the results.

Answer (score 0):

Because the link you are specifying in **start_urls** is actually the link of the second page. If you open it, you'll see there's no `<a>` tag for the current page. That's why page 2 isn't reaching `target_page` and therefore, you should point **start_urls** to:

https://data.ok.gov/browse?f[0]=bundle_name%3ADataset&f[1]=im_field_categories%3A4191

This code should help you:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request


class DataokspiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'dataoksp'
    allowed_domains = ['data.ok.gov']
    start_urls = ["https://data.ok.gov/browse?f[0]=bundle_name%3ADataset&f[1]=im_field_categories%3A4191",]

    def parse(self, response):
        for titles in response.css('.title a'):
            name = titles.css("::text").extract_first()
            yield {'Name':name}

        next_page = response.xpath('//li[@class="pager-next"]/a/@href').extract_first()
        if next_page:
            yield Request("https://data.ok.gov{}".format(next_page), callback=self.parse)
```

**Stats** (see `item_scraped_count`):

```
{
    'downloader/request_bytes': 2094,
    'downloader/request_count': 6,
    'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 6,
    'downloader/response_bytes': 45666,
    'downloader/response_count': 6,
    'downloader/response_status_count/200': 6,
    'finish_reason': 'finished',
    'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 19, 7, 23, 47, 801934),
    'item_scraped_count': 46,
    'log_count/DEBUG': 53,
    'log_count/INFO': 7,
    'memusage/max': 47509504,
    'memusage/startup': 47509504,
    'request_depth_max': 4,
    'response_received_count': 6,
    'scheduler/dequeued': 5,
    'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 5,
    'scheduler/enqueued': 5,
    'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 5,
    'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 19, 7, 23, 46, 59360)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andrés Pérez-Albela H., for your answer. This solution definitely works and before posting here I tried with it as well. However, there is a built-in style in scrapy to parse the data from first page which is `parse_start_url`, I actually expected my script to be built upon that guideline. Thanks again.

Comment: @Topto I'm glad my answer helped. If it answers your question please set it as the selected answer and upvote in case you value my support.

Comment: @Topto `parse_start_url` is for **CrawlSpider** and not for **Spider**. That said, if you would need to override it you'll need to inherit from CrawlSpider first. Though, CrawlSpider is not needed for your use case since you don't need rules and, also, the same behavior can be reproduced with the code I added to my answer (with just Spider).